# Failed to add persistent remember me to Spring application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, remember-me

I followed [this guide](http://javasampleapproach.com/spring-framework/spring-security/configure-persistent-token-remember-me-authentication-persistent-token-approach-spring-boot) to setup a Remember Me mechanism on my Spring Boot 2 application, without success. Even if I check the remember me checkbox at login, no remember me cookie is generated. No exception is thrown.

This is my SecurityConfiguration.java:

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenRepository;

import it.niuma.cse.service.UserDetailsServiceImp;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public UserDetailsServiceImp  userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

     @Bean
        public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
            return bCryptPasswordEncoder;
        }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/loginMe", "/logout").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/fornitore/**").hasRole("USER")
        .antMatchers("/ruolo/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.authorizeRequests().and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/accessDenied");

        http.authorizeRequests().and().formLogin()//
         // Submit URL of login page.
        .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check") // Submit URL
        .loginPage("/loginMe")//
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/loginOK")//
        .failureUrl("/loginMe?error=true")//
        .usernameParameter("username")//
        .passwordParameter("password")
         // Config for Logout Page
        .and()
        .rememberMe()
            .rememberMeCookieName("remember-me")
            .tokenValiditySeconds(24 * 60 * 60)
            .tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository())
         .and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/loginMe");
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistentTokenRepository persistentTokenRepository() {
        JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl tokenRepository = new JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl();
        tokenRepository.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return tokenRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/assets/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/img/**", "/plugins/**" , "/i18n/**");
    }
}
```